# Cannot read property of undefined error Angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm new to angularjs and html and I'm getting this error, "Cannot read property 'Dateofbirth' of undefined error". I did a little debuging and found out that for some reason, my api call is getting skipped. This is what the code looks like ...

```
profile.controller("profileController", ["$scope","$resource", function($scope, $resource) {

// get the user id
$scope.userid = sessionStorage["cerestiuserid"];

// json we get from server
$scope.apicall = sessionStorage["cerestihome"];     

//grabs the user we want
if(typeof sessionStorage["infos"] == "undefined") {

    $scope.userResource = $resource($scope.apicall + "/api/userprofile/", {Userid:$scope.userid}, {'get':{method: 'POST'}});

    //fetch JSON        
THIS PART OF CODE IS SKIPPED FOR SOME REASON--->    $scope.userResource.get(function(result, putResponseHeaders) {

        // get the name field
        $scope.infos = result;
        sessionStorage["infos"] = JSON.stringify(result);

    });

} else {

    $scope.infos = JSON.parse(sessionStorage["infos"]);
}

// show/hide helper function
$scope.hide = function() {

        var DOB = JSON.stringify($scope.infos.Dateofbirth.Valid);
        var lang_size = $scope.infos.Languages.length;
        var Ethn = JSON.stringify($scope.infos.Ethnicity.Valid);


        // check if the JSONS are empty
        if ( DOB === 'false' & Ethn === 'false' & lang_size === 0) {
            return 'true';
        }
        else {
            // one of the JSON's have elements
            return 'false';
        }


        // check if the JSONS are empty
        if ( DOB === 'false' & Ethn === 'false' & lang_size === 0) {
            return 'true';
        }

        // one of the JSON's have elements
        return 'false';

};  

}]);
```

And this is the html code where I call the function and use the JSONs ...

```
<div class="dl-horizontal" style="margin-top:10px">
        <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
                <div ng-show="infos.Dateofbirth.Valid == true">
                    <dt> Date of Birth </dt>
                    <dd> {{infos.Dateofbirth.Date}} </dd>
                </div>

                <div ng-show="infos.Ethnicity.Valid == true">
                    <dt> Ethnicity </dt>
                    <dd> {{infos.Ethnicity.String}} </dd>
                </div>

                <div ng-hide="infos.Languages.length == 0"> 
                    <dt> Language </dt>
                    <dd>
                        <div ng-repeat="info in infos.Languages">
                            <div>{{info}}&nbsp;</div>
                        </div>
                    </dd>
                </div>

            <div ng-show="hide()">
                <p>No information to show</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advanced

Comment: When you say that line is skipped, are you watching network traffic and not seeing the call being made? Remember that it will be an asynchronous call. Are you getting an error from the server? Also, it seems odd to use an action name of `get` for a POST